Pandas - Merge DataFrame, keep non-null values on common columns, keep average on another column
I am working with two DataFrames, defined as such:
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a', 0.95], [2, 'b', 0.92], [3, 'c',  0.91]], columns=['id','value','similarity'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 'c', 0.93], [4, 'd', 0.92], [5, 'e',  0.99]], columns=['id','value','similarity'])


df1
id  name   similarity
1   a      0.95
2   b      0.92
3   c      0.91

df2
id  name   similarity
3   c      0.93
4   d      0.92
5   e      0.99

I now want to combine both DataFrames by the key attribute id, while avoiding the creation of NaNs in the name column. For this, I use pd.combine_first, as suggested in this answer, to get this:
df3 = df1.set_index('id').combine_first(df2.set_index('id'))
df3

id  name   similarity   
1   a      0.95
2   b      0.92
3   c      0.91
4   d      0.92
5   e      0.99

However, I have an additional requirement. When a similarity value exists on both sets, I want to take their average as the new value. So for instance my desired output would be something like:
id  name  similarity    
1   a      0.95
2   b      0.92
3   c      0.92 <-- (0.91 + 0.93 / 2)
4   d      0.92
5   e      0.99

Preferably using pandas or numpy, how can I average similarities when both DataFrames have a value?

I'm assuming name is the same when id is the same, can you confirm that this is correct?

@mozway Yes, that is the case.

Thanks, if not you could have used the second approach in my answer ;)

You can concat, then groupby.mean:
out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['id', 'value'], as_index=False).mean()

Output:
   id value  similarity
0   1     a        0.95
1   2     b        0.92
2   3     c        0.92
3   4     d        0.92
4   5     e        0.99

If you want to have the combine_first behavior for some columns and the average for others, you could use groupby.agg with first/mean depending on the columns:
df1['x'] = 'one'
df2['x'] = 'two'

out = (pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['id', 'value'], as_index=False)
         .agg({'similarity': 'mean', 'x': 'first'})
      )

Output:
   id value  similarity    x
0   1     a        0.95  one
1   2     b        0.92  one
2   3     c        0.92  one
3   4     d        0.92  two
4   5     e        0.99  two

weighted average
import numpy as np

out = (pd.concat([df1.assign(w=0.7), df2.assign(w=0.3)])
         .groupby(['id', 'value'])
         .apply(lambda x: np.average(x['similarity'], weights=x['w']),
                include_groups=False)
         .reset_index(name='weighted_avg')
      )

Output:
   id value  weighted_avg
0   1     a         0.950
1   2     b         0.920
2   3     c         0.916
3   4     d         0.920
4   5     e         0.990

or:
g = (pd.concat([df1.assign(w=0.7), df2.assign(w=0.3)])
       .eval('weighted_avg = similarity * w')
       .groupby(['id', 'value'])
    )
out = (g.first()
        .assign(weighted_avg=g['weighted_avg'].sum()/g['w'].sum())
        .reset_index()
      )

Output:
   id value  similarity    w  weighted_avg
0   1     a        0.95  0.7         0.950
1   2     b        0.92  0.7         0.920
2   3     c        0.91  0.7         0.916
3   4     d        0.92  0.3         0.920
4   5     e        0.99  0.3         0.990


Out of curiosity, would it be possible to calculate a weighted average with your method? Let's say the similarity score in df1 is worth 70% and the one in df2 the remaining 30%, can this be achieved with groupby.mean?

@Johnny not directly, but this is possible. See update

   import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import janitor
    from janitor.functions.coalesce import coalesce
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a', 0.95], [2, 'b', 0.92], [3, 'c', 0.91]], columns=['id', 'name', 'similarity'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 'c', 0.93], [4, 'd', 0.92], [5, 'e', 0.99]], columns=['id', 'name', 'similarity'])
    
    # The Best 
    with_concatGroupbyAgg = pd.concat([df1, df2]) \
        .groupby('id', as_index=False) \
        .agg({
            'name': 'first',  # Take the first non-null value in 'name'
            'similarity': 'mean'  # Take the average of 'similarity'
        })
    
    print(with_concatGroupbyAgg)
    
    aa = df1.merge(df2,how ='outer', on = 'id', suffixes = ('_df1','_df2'))
    print(aa)
    '''
       id  name_df1  similarity_df1 name_df2  similarity_df2
    0   1        a            0.95      NaN             NaN
    1   2        b            0.92      NaN             NaN
    2   3        c            0.91        c            0.93
    3   4      NaN             NaN        d            0.92
    4   5      NaN             NaN        e            0.99
    '''
    bb = aa.assign(
    similarity = lambda x : x[['similarity_df1','similarity_df2']].mean(axis=1)    
    )
    print(bb)
    '''
       id name_df1  similarity_df1 name_df2  similarity_df2  similarity
    0   1        a            0.95      NaN             NaN        0.95
    1   2        b            0.92      NaN             NaN        0.92
    2   3        c            0.91        c            0.93        0.92
    3   4      NaN             NaN        d            0.92        0.92
    4   5      NaN             NaN        e            0.99        0.99
    '''
    #coalesce from pyjanitor. 
    with_pyjanitor_coalesce = bb.coalesce(
    ['name_df1','name_df2'],target_column_name = 'name'    
    ).loc[:,['id','name','similarity']]
    print(with_pyjanitor_coalesce)
    '''
       id name  similarity
    0   1    a        0.95
    1   2    b        0.92
    2   3    c        0.92
    3   4    d        0.92
    4   5    e        0.99
    '''
    # combine_first from pandas.
    with_pandas_combine_first  = bb.assign(
    name  = lambda x : x['name_df1'].combine_first(x['name_df2'])    
    ).loc[:,['id','name','similarity']]
    print(with_pandas_combine_first)
    '''
       id name  similarity
    0   1    a        0.95
    1   2    b        0.92
    2   3    c        0.92
    3   4    d        0.92
    4   5    e        0.99
    '''

